# Chart Rerenders because it is inside a col with onMouseEnter, but i dont want the chart to rerender, i just want buttons to be visible on MouseEnter

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

so i want my buttons to be visible when i hover on any part of the div, but since the chart is in this div it keeps rerendering when i hover. i dont want it to keep rerendering

```
<Col onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} style={{ position: 'relative'}} >
          <Row>
                {(isDivHovered) && ( <>
                    <Col >
                        <Button 
                            block 
                            className='py-1 button-label ' 
                            onClick={() => open
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col >
                        <Button 
                            block 
                            className='py-1 button-label ' 
                            onClick={() => close 
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                </>
                )}
                
            </Row>
            <Row className="w-100">
                <Col className="col-12 col-xl-6 p-0">
                    <chart
                        data = {{
                            labels: fruit, 
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: fruits,
                                    data: fruitData,
                                    backgroundColor: tableColors
                                }
                            ]
                        }}
                        options = {tableOptions}
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col className='my-auto'>
                    {fruitslabel}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Col>
```

i tried moving onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} to the row with the buttons but that didnt allow the buttons to show when i hovered anywhere in the div. i also tried using react memo but it didn't change anything.